# ld64.so present in ldd, missing at runtime

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ldd

I am compiling some code, and for various reasons I'm doing it statically. On my Ubuntu 12.04 / gcc 4.6.3 machine it compiles executes fine, and is fully static:

```
> ldd mycode
    not a dynamic executable
```

So far so good.
But I also need to run it on another machine, a Scientific Linux 5 system, running gcc 4.5.3. For some reason here, ldd has some dynamic libs left over:

```
> ldd mycode
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd75fd000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/swift/gcc-4.5.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b4bafab2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000398ca00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000398c600000)
    /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000398c200000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/swift/gcc-4.5.3/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b4bafdb8000)
```

Which is, in itself, fine. The code compiles and links OK, and as you can see from ldd, all the dependencies are resolved. However, when I try to execute it on the SL machine, it fails:

```
> ./mycode
  /lib/ld64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

As far as I can see therefore, at execute time for some reason the `/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` link is not being resolved, even though ldd does it. Of course, on machines where I have root access I can solve this by making a sym link from ld-linux-x84..blah to /lib/ld64.so.1 but this is a rather pants solution and I can't apply it to our cluster. If I compile the whole thing dynamically it works fine, but this means installing all the 3rd party libraries I'm compiling against on a bunch of machines which I wanted to avoid. Finally, all the dependencies against which I compile are also used by another project, also compiled with cmake, and in that case I have no problem, and ldd  actually lists the /lib64/ld-linux...blah direct, not a call to /lib/ld64.so.

So - why is this happening? Why can I compile and link the code OK, ldd it OK, and yet not execute it? Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Comment: When you compile something on a system significantly newer than the system you try to execute it on, all kind of weird incompatibilities can occur.

Comment: Try adding `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to linking options

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually not compiling it on a newer system than I execute it on. I realise I didn't say that- whoops! For the SL system with the older gcc I completely recompiled the code from scratch, on that system - it compiled and linked fine on that machine, but then gave me the afforementioned linker output and execute error. I will try the line above, although I thought part of the point of cmake was precisely so I don't have to worry about that sort of thing!

Answer (score 6):

OK, I think I cracked this in the end. It was basically the linker arguments being passed by cmake, which were a nasty combination of static and dynamic ones, However, adding the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt fixed it:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (mytarget PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC 1)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (mytarget PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I meet same problem on a cenos7 system.
and the os installed ld-linux i386 and x86_64 at same time.
you can see ld-linux under /lib is a i386 version by `objdump -a /lib/ld-linux.so`
and I:

```
rm /lib/ld-*.so
ln -s ld64.so.1 /lib64/ld-linux.so
```

problem solved.